# Show this combinatorical identity

Tags: combinatorics

$$\sum_{k=0}^m {n \choose k} {n-k \choose m-k} = 2^m {n \choose m}, m<n$$

I know that $2^m$ represents the number of subsets of a set of length $m$, which I can see there being a connection to the ${n \choose k}$ term, but I can't see how the combination it's multiplied by affects this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## A "double-counting" proof

Let $m<n$ be two positive integers. We have $n$ objects, and we want to choose $m$ of them to paint them, then choose some of the painted objects (possibly none of them) to store them on a box. We have two ways to do this

First, we can select the $m$ objects to be painted ($\binom{n}{m}$ ways), and then the subset to be placed inside the box ($2^m$ waks). Multiplicative principle gives us

$$ \binom{n}{m}2^m $$

to do this. Another way is first select the number of objets we want to put on the box, $k$ (of course, $0\leq k \leq m$), then select the box-objects ($\binom{n}{k}$ ways), and then the rest of painted objects ($m-k$ object), in $\binom{n-k}{m-k}$ ways. This way, we have

$$ \binom{n}{k} \binom{n-k}{m-k}$$

ways to do this, and adding the (disjoint) cases for $k=0, 1, \dots, m$ we have

$$ \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \binom{n-k}{m-k}$$

options. We counted the same number in two different ways, so they have to be equal:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \binom{n-k}{m-k} = 2^m \binom{n}{m} $$

## An algebraic proof

$$\begin{align*} 
& \sum_{k=0}^m  \binom{n}{k} \binom{n-k}{m-k} \\
=& \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{n!}{k! (n-k)!}\cdot \frac{(n-k)!}{(m-k)!(n-m)!} \\
=& \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{n!}{k!(m-k)!(n-m)!}\\
=& \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{n!}{(n-m)!m!}\cdot \frac{m!}{k!(m-k)!} \\
=& \sum_{k=0}^m \binom{n}{m} \binom{m}{k} \\
=& \binom{n}{m} \sum_{k=0}^m \binom{m}{k} \\
=& \binom{n}{m} \cdot 2^m
\end{align*} $$

Comment: FANTASTIC first post. Take my reputation. I throw it at you abundantly. Great use of MathJax, great job posting two FANTASTIC answers. +1 all around.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> An analytical approach:

\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 0}^{m}{n \choose k}{n - k \choose m - k} & =
\bracks{z^{m}}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}z^{\ell}
\bracks{\sum_{k = 0}^{\ell}{n \choose k}{n - k \choose \ell - k}} =
\bracks{z^{m}}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{n \choose k}
\sum_{\ell = k}^{\infty}{n - k \choose \ell - k}z^{\ell}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{z^{m}}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{n \choose k}
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}{n - k \choose \ell}z^{\ell + k} =
\bracks{z^{m}}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{n \choose k}z^{k}
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}{n - k \choose \ell}z^{\ell}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{z^{m}}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{n \choose k}z^{k}\pars{1 + z}^{n - k} =
\bracks{z^{m}}\bracks{\pars{1 + z}^{n}
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{n \choose k}\pars{z \over 1 + z}^{k}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{z^{m}}\bracks{\pars{1 + z}^{n}\pars{1 + {z \over 1 + z}}^{n}} =
\bracks{z^{m}}\pars{1 + 2z}^{n}
=
\bracks{z^{m}}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{n}{n \choose \ell}\pars{2z}^{\ell}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{\ds{{n \choose m}2^{m}}}
\end{align}